# Inconsistent getServerSideProps behaviour using NextJS in vercel

Tags: redirect, next.js, routes, vercel, supabase

I have the following setup

- `/template`. Loads a page that shows all the templates owned by the current user.
- `/template/new`. Loads a page that allows the user to create a template and save it.
- `/api/save-template`. Receives the frontend call made from `/template/new` and handles storing it on the db.

With those routes, a typical use case is the following:

1. User ends up somehow (irrelevant) on `/template/new`.
2. User creates a template and hit "save". A spiner shows up while saving happens.
3. Template payload is sent via POST HTTP request to `/api/save-template`.
4. `/api/save-template` route handles the saving successfully and responds with a status `200`.
5. The spinner finishes and the user is redirected to `/template`, where the newly created template should hopefully show up.

The problem here is on point 5, where in some scenarios, the newly created template doesn't show up. Here's what happens on different scenarios. The app could be running either using `next dev`, `next build && next start`, or deployed on vercel. The database could either be hosted locally on docker, or on the cloud using supabase.

| db \ app | `next dev` | `next build...` | vercel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| docker | ✅ | ✅ | haven't tried |
| supabase | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |

One thing to keep in mind, which might be related to the reason this is not working, is that the redirection is made on the frontend using `router.push('/template')`.

I'm also checking on the client side what templates are available when reaching point 5. I've confirmed this is not a db delay issue because the templates are found by the client. For those checks I'm using the following code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const checkSupabase = async () => {
      const templatesResponse = await supabase
        .from<Template[]>('Template')
        .select('*')
      const templates = templatesResponse.data
      console.log('templates found from useEffect')
      console.log(templates)
    }

    checkSupabase()
  }, [])
```

And the last thing I want to point out is that the logs I get from vercel make me think the `getServerSideProps` is not called. I'm logging `templates found from getServerSideProps` to see what's available on that function. I see the log before creating the template (time 21:31:24:00), and then the `/api/save-template` being hit (time 21:31:47:11), but I don't see the second request to `/template` after the redirect. The logs –note the order is newest on the top– are:

```
21:31:47:11 - [POST] /api/save-template


21:31:24:00 - [GET] /template
templates found from getServerSideProps
[]
```

### Questions

1. How is it that I don't see a second log for `[GET] /template` or the `templates found from getServerSideProps` log? Is it not being fired?
2. If `getServerSideProps` is not fired, how come this works when the app is running locally?
3. Is there a consistent solution for this use case? I guess it must be quite common to want to see recently created data.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the template page only showing 404 when the client-side redirect happens, or is it still persistent even after your manually reload the page?

Comment: The template page actually never shows a 404. It loads up, but it shows stale data, since getServerSideProps is not run. When I reload, it runs and the updated data shows up. It also shows updated data if I navigate to a different place using the menu (next links), and then go to /template again using the menu.